# Using one app function attribute into another app function

Tags: python, django

I need help

For example , i have two app in my project ,Blog and Post .

In Blog app i have a function with name Promo as

```
def Promo():
    global x
    x= 10
    y= 20
    c= x + y
return c
```

In second app Post , i have Code function and i want use **x** in this function

```
def Code():
    d = x + 10
return d
```

But error occurred something like that : **global name 'x' is not defined**

How can i use x value into Code function that located in Post app in same project ?

Comment: NEVER use mutable globals in Django - it's garanteed to play havoc with your data once in production (think about how a web server - specially a multiprocess based one, which is the norm - handle incoming requests from various users).  If you want to share state between requests, either use a proper `Model` to store it in db or, if it's transiant data, store it in sessions.

Comment: Can you write your idea on basis of my example code ?

Comment: Well send me the full functional and technical specs and I'll make you a commercial offer. My fees start at €800 a day.

Comment: Thanks  but i will do it by storing function result in session by myself )

Comment: Yes I think it will be much faster and way cheaper ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just create variable X in a separate ".py" folder and use import where you need to use.

Comment: Worst idea ever, specially in the context of a multiprocess (prefork) web server.

Comment: No . My real functions isn't sample as i write ? this function's call other webserver's and also called by ajax .So i need however to use X variable into second app

Comment: Best idea is store a app function result in session and use it in second app function as variable